# How to calculate a particular index in R

Tags: r

[image]

Hello everyone, I need your help for the calculation of this expression. I have a dataframe with income streams (made of 5 "t" periods) from different years. What I need is a command to make R understand the highlighted part of the formula under the summation symbol. I need R to multiplicate when there is a loss for the l0 coefficient, and when there is a gain for the g0 gain coefficient.

```
delta=15/16
g0=16/15
l0=1
```

```
  2004 2006 2008 2010 2012
1   5    10   12   14   8
2   13   5    4    3    1
3   4    2    1    8    10
```

so if this is the dataframe, for obs number 1 I need to calculate this way:

```
[(10-5)*15/16^(4-1)+(12-10)*15/16^(3-1)+(14-12)*15/16^(2-1)]*16/15+[(8-14)*15/16^(1-1)]*1
```

for obs number 2 this way:

```
[(5-13)*15/16^(4-1)+(4-5)*15/16^(3-1)+(3-4)*15/16^(2-1)+(1-3)*15/16^(1-1)]*1
```

for obs 3 this way:

```
[(2-4)*15/16^(4-1)+(1-2)*15/16^(3-1)]*1 +[(8-1)*15/16^(2-1)+(10-8)*15/16^(1-1)]*16/15
```

Comment: what is \delta^(t-1)? a function or a coefficient?

Comment: "\delta^(t-1)" is just a coefficient. Which by the way is given by 16/15^(t-1), and t can vary from 0 to 4.

Comment: R statements defining example data could be helpful.

Comment: "\delta^(t-1)" is just a coefficient. Which by the way is given by 16/15^(t-1), and t can vary from 0 to 4. Sorry if I didn't wrote any example but my problem is that I have no idea where to start for calculating this expression. To make you to make you guys understand the whole thing: x are the income streams, I have 5 streams so we have 5 t's(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), delta is just a coefficient, and l0 is the coefficient for the losses(which is when xt>xt-1) and g0 is the coefficient for the gains (which is when xt<xt-1).

Comment: is it (15/16)^(t-1) or 15/16^(t-1)? not clear

Comment: is it (15/16)^(t-1), thank you very much.

Comment: I have updated my solution, please check if it is what you need for your dataset @AlessandroGallo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data.frame is generated as below

```
x1 <- c(5,10,12,14,8)
x2 <- c(13,5,4,3,1)
x3 <- c(4,2,1,8,10)
df <- as.data.frame(rbind(x1,x2,x3))
rownames(df) <- as.character(c(1,2,3))
colnames(df) <- as.character(c(2004,2006,2008,2010,2012))
```

then you can use the following for you purpose:

```
I <- function(x, delta = 15/16, g0 = 16/15, l0 = 1) {
  dx <- diff(x)
  sum(sapply(seq_along(dx), function(k) dx[k]*delta**(length(dx)-k)*ifelse(dx[k]>0, g0,l0)))
}
r <- apply(df, 1, I)
```

where `I` is the function as you stated

Comment: Check out how I edited the comment. Maybe now can be a little more clear. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Ok that's perfect! And if i would like to do also: [(5-10)*15/16^(4-1)+(10-12)*15/16^(3-1)+(12-14)*15/16^(2-1)]*16/15+[(14-8)*15/16^(1-1)]*1, for the observation n 1 and [(13-5)*15/16^(4-1)+(5-4)*15/16^(3-1)+(4-3)*15/16^(2-1)+(3-1)*15/16^(1-1)]*1 so on for the third. How should I change the code? Thank you very much in advance you saved my thesis.

Comment: @AlessandroGallo then use `I <- function(x, delta = 1/16, g0 = 16/15, l0 = 1) {
  dx <- diff(x)
  sum(sapply(seq_along(dx), function(k) 15*dx[k]*delta**(length(dx)-k)*ifelse(dx[k]>0, g0,l0)))
}`

Comment: ThomasisCoding thank you very much, and sorry if I insist, but the second function you proposed is not working as I wish if I change "delta" and "g0" parameters. if i place delta=0.9 and g0=15/16 is not giving the correct result.

Comment: I suggest you try to understand your formula thoroughly before coding, then you will find if you missed something since it is impossible other than you to know what exactly you should do  @AlessandroGallo

Comment: That's what I'm doing now. Thank you very much for your help